# Adding windows to stacking area and not main window with awesome window manager

Tags: awesome-wm

Is it possible to configure awesome so that when new windows are created, they are added to stacking area instead of as a new main window?

Alternative, if it's configured with multiple main windows, can I add it as the second main window instead of as the main.

I usually have a main window that I work on, and spawn other apps via shortcuts, and would like the main window to stay where it is (as main window).

ty

Answer (score 2):

If you are using part of the default rc.lua then just find the line `-- awful.client.setslave(c)` and remove `--` from it, now your windows will open up in the stacking pane.

If you aren't using the default rc.lua then just add `awful.client.setslave(c)` to the codeblock starting with `client.connect_signal("manage", function (c, startup)`